# comparing multiple files and columns using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files and I would like to match column 2 and 3 from `file1` with column 2 and 3 from `file3`. If the pattern is found, I would like to output the whole line from `file2` with, in addition column 1 from `file1` at the end:

I have the following two file-types: 
(`file2` has a lot of columns (`tab` seperated) but, columns 2 and 3 can match 2 and three from `file1`. )

*file1*

```
name1 1 12343442 
name2 2 32434242
name3 3 982793749
```

*file2*

```
a 1 12343442 text1  text2  text3 value0 value2 
a 1 12343442 text1  text2  text3 value2 value3 
a 1 12348888 text1  text2  text3 value0 value2   
b 3 982793749 text1  text4  text3 value1 value11
b 2 982793749 text1  text4  text3 value1 value11
```

desired output

```
a 1 12343442 text1  text2  text3 value0 value2 name1
a 1 12343442 text1  text2  text3 value2 value3 name1
b 3 982793749 text1  text4  text3 value1 value11 name3
```

I have tried doing this using `awk`. Something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} ('$2 FS $3' in a) {print $0, a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

But it doesnt work. Even if I just try to match the third columns it does not work. 
The files are pretty big *>500mb* so I would like to read them only once. 
Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one-liner should work :

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$2FS$3]=$1;next}$2FS$3 in a{print $0,a[$2FS$3]}' file1 file2
```

in your codes

- you had `a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next`, you were confused by the `key` and `value`. here you wanted the `$2FS$3` to be key, and `$1` to be the value.
- `('$2 FS $3' in a)` is not correct either, remove the single-quotes